Chart Not Displaying Top/Bottom Logic Based on High/Low Comparisons
this is my first time coding with Pine Script. I’m encountering an issue while coding an indicator for my strategy and would really appreciate your help.
Objective of the indicator: Identify Tops and Bottoms.
Logic of the indicator:
To identify a Top, the following conditions must be met:
The highest price of the last 3 candles (including the current candle and the previous 2 candles) must be higher than the highest price of the last 12 candles (including the current candle and the previous 11 candles).
The current candle must close below the lowest point of the previous candle.
The volume of this "Top" candle must be greater than the Volume MA 20.
For a Bottom, the conditions are reversed.
Here is my code:
//@version=5

indicator("My test indicator", overlay=true)

// Volume MA

maLength = 20 // Value for Volume MA

volumeMA = ta.sma(volume, maLength)

// Calculate High/Low

highest3 = ta.highest(high, 3)

lowest3 = ta.lowest(low, 3)

highest12 = ta.highest(high, 12)

lowest12 = ta.lowest(low, 12)

// Logic for comparison

isHigher = (highest3 > highest12)

isLower = (lowest3 < lowest12)

// Condition for detecting tops

isTop = (close < low[1]) and (volume > volumeMA) and isHigher

isBottom = (close > high[1]) and (volume > volumeMA) and isLower

// Plotting

plotshape(isTop, title="High", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small)

plotshape(isBottom, title="Low", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)

The code works fine with conditions 2 and 3. However, when I implement the comparison for the price levels (condition 1 using isHigher and isLower), nothing appears on the chart.
Please help me fix this part. Thank you so much!

This is because if highest3 is greater than highest12 than highest12 equals highest3.
You would need to check if they are equal to each other or you could do something like checking if it was higher than the highest9 from 3 bars ago.

//@version=6
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

h3 = ta.highest(high,3)
h12 = ta.highest(high,12)
h9 = ta.highest(high,9)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high, 'Highest 3: ' + str.tostring(h3,format.mintick) + '\nHighest 12: ' + str.tostring(h12,format.mintick) + '\nHighest 9[3]: ' + str.tostring(h9[3],format.mintick))

